# Cannot get Fitbit API working in React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, mobile, expo

I can successfully retrieve the auth token from fitbit's API however when i try to use this token with a code challenge i get the error ' Error: [Error: HTTP Error: 400 - {"errors":[{"errorType":"invalid_grant","message":"Authorization code verifier invalid'

This is my current code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import { makeRedirectUri, useAuthRequest } from 'expo-auth-session';
import base64 from 'react-native-base64';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import * as Crypto from 'expo-crypto';

// Assuming these utilities are defined as previously discussed
export const generateCodeVerifier = () => {
  let verifier = uuidv4().replace(/-/g, '') + uuidv4().replace(/-/g, '');
  verifier = verifier.substring(0, 128); // Ensure the verifier's length
  return verifier;
};

export const generateCodeChallenge = async (verifier) => {
  const hashed = await Crypto.digestStringAsync(
    Crypto.CryptoDigestAlgorithm.SHA256,
    verifier,
    { encoding: Crypto.CryptoEncoding.BASE64 }
  );
  const challenge = hashed.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '');
  console.log(`Generated Code Challenge: ${challenge}`); // Debugging log
  return challenge;
};

export const saveCodeVerifier = async (verifier) => {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('codeVerifier', verifier);
};

export const getCodeVerifier = async () => {
  return await AsyncStorage.getItem('codeVerifier');
};

// Updated Integrations component with added logs for debugging
export default function Integrations() {
  const [codeChallenge, setCodeChallenge] = useState('');
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const verifier = generateCodeVerifier();
      console.log(`Code Verifier (for storage): ${verifier}`); // Debugging log
      await saveCodeVerifier(verifier);
      const challenge = await generateCodeChallenge(verifier);
      setCodeChallenge(challenge);
    })();
  }, []);

  // No changes in the authorization request setup
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID', // Ensure this is set correctly
      scopes: ['activity', 'sleep'],
      redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({ scheme: 'exp://' }),
      codeChallenge,
      codeChallengeMethod: 'S256',
    },
    {
      authorizationEndpoint: 'https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize',
      tokenEndpoint: 'https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token',
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === 'success') {
      const { code } = response.params;
      console.log(`Authorization Code: ${code}`); // Debugging log
      fetchAccessToken(code);
    }
  }, [response]);

  const fetchAccessToken = async (code) => {
    const verifier = await getCodeVerifier();
    console.log(`Code Verifier (for token request): ${verifier}`); // Debugging log

    // Update the client ID and secret as needed
    const clientId = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
    const clientSecret = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET';
    const credentials = `${clientId}:${clientSecret}`;
    const encodedCredentials = base64.encode(credentials);

    const headers = {
      'Authorization': `Basic ${encodedCredentials}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    };

    const body = new URLSearchParams({
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      redirect_uri: makeRedirectUri({ scheme: 'exp://' }),
      code,
      client_id: clientId,
      code_verifier: verifier,
    });

    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: body.toString(),
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      if (!response.ok) {
        console.error('HTTP Error:', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)); // Enhanced error log
        throw new Error(`HTTP Error: ${response.status} - ${data.errors.map(err => err.message).join(', ')}`);
      }

      console.log('Token Response Success:', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)); // Debugging log
      setToken(data.access_token);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Fetch Token Error:', error.message); // Enhanced error log
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        disabled={!request || !codeChallenge}
        title="Login with Fitbit"
        onPress={() => {
          console.log('Initiating login...');
          promptAsync();
        }}
      />
      {token && <Text>Access Token: {token}</Text>}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated